# Clipping gradients by global norm using the TensorFlow Keras API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tf.keras

Gradient clipping is one solution to the exploding gradient problem in deep learning. The `tf.keras` API allows users to use a variation of gradient clipping by passing [`clipnorm` or `clipvalue`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L242-L246) to any `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`.

However, the current implementation clips the gradient of each weight independently of the gradients of the other weights. [This is done in the `_compute_gradients` method of the `Optimizer` class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py#L358-L364):

```py
      if hasattr(self, "clipnorm"):
        grads = [clip_ops.clip_by_norm(g, self.clipnorm) for g in grads]
      if hasattr(self, "clipvalue"):
        grads = [
            clip_ops.clip_by_value(g, -self.clipvalue, self.clipvalue)
            for g in grads
        ]
```

This has the potential disadvantage of changing the descent direction, whereas if the gradients were clipped by their *global* norm, then the direction would remain unchanged.

TensorFlow has a [`clip_by_global_norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_global_norm) function which can scale a list of tensors to bound their global norm, but it's not used by the `Optimizer` class.

---

### Question

Is there a way to get `tf.keras` optimizers to clip gradients by global norm *without* writing custom training logic (i.e., manually computing gradients using `tf.GradientTape` followed by calling `apply_gradients`)?

I'm not opposed to the `tf.GradientTape` solution, but I'm wondering if there's another way.

Comment: Looks like someone suggested changing the implementation to use clip_by_global_norm: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29108